# UIWebview scrollsToTop not working when a UIScrollview is present as subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm having an issue with `setScrollsToTop:` on UIWebView. the webview is a subview of the root view controller and on `viewDidLoad` I set:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setScrollsToTop:YES];
```

However when I then tap the status bar the webview won't scroll to the top. On another modal tableViewController inside the app it works fine, without even setting `setScrollsToTop:YES`. This is the code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` inside the app delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.f = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.f;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

How can I make it work?

EDIT: It seems like a UIScrollview that is in the same view is causing the problem. How can I make it work with the UIScrollView?

Comment: For clarification: Do you mean that by tapping on status bar, you want the HTML page that is being loaded in UIWebView, scroll to top? Right?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `setScrollsToTop:NO` on the UIScrollView.

According to the [docs on setScrollsToTop: in UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop),

> This gesture works on a single visible scroll view; if there are
>   multiple scroll views (for example, a date picker) with this property
>   set, or if the delegate returns NO in scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:,
>   UIScrollView ignores the request.

Answer (score 0):

use the answer here: [UIScrollView + UIWebView = NO scrollsToTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175281/uiscrollview-uiwebview-no-scrollstotop)

worked for me like a charm.

i had a UIScrollView with a UIWebView embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those code will solve you problem if I get the problem.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

CGSize containerSize = self.view.frame.size;
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, containerSize.wdith, containerSize.height - 65);
```

Sometime the self.automaticallyAdjestsScrollViewInsets  is not wokring as usual. So, just turn off it.

Comment: Oh, I just has not understood you problem. sorry