# UITableView's, UIWebViews and the scrollsToTop Property = Trouble

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, scroll, uiscrollview

My app has a `UITableView`. That UITableView has a header view, which is a `UIWebView`.

By default, scroll views have their `scrollsToTop` property set to `YES`, which will enable the user to tap the status bar to scroll to the top of the scroll view.

When there are two scroll views embedded in one view, that both have their `scrollsToTop` property set to `YES`, tapping the status bar does nothing.

The solution is to set one of the `scrollsToTop` properties to `NO`. That re-enables tapping the status bar.

Now here's the problem: UIWebView doesn't expose it's scroll view, and as a result, there is no access to it's `scrollsToTop` property. I only want the table view to scroll to the top when the status bar is tapped, not the web view.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a scrollView property, which is preferred:

```
myWebView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

This question contains the answer:

[iPhone OS: Tap status bar to scroll to top doesn't work after remove/add back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361614/iphone-os-tap-status-bar-to-scroll-to-top-doesnt-work-after-remove-add-back)

I couldn't find it previously since it was asked differently and on a slightly different topic, but the result is the same.

So the outcome was to walk through the subviews until you find the scroll view. I've done this before in other apps and didn't think of it in this case. It should be App-Store-Safe, as I have apps on the store that use this idea.

A category on UIWebView to enable or disable scrolling to top:

```
@implementation UIWebView (UIWebViewScrollToTopAdditions)

- (void)setScrollsToTop:(BOOL)scrollsToTop
{
    if ([[self subviews] count] > 0)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([scrollView respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollsToTop:)])
        {
            [scrollView setScrollsToTop:scrollsToTop];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

This often happens because all scrollviews have a default value. When new scrollviews or webviews are created they will have `scrollsToTop` set to YES. I've written a simple category for this specific issue:

```
-[UIScrollView makeOnlyThisScrollViewScrollToTopOnStatusBarTap];
```

https://gist.github.com/hfossli/6776203

It basically sets scrollsToTop to `NO` on all other scrollViews than the one you are specifying + taking care of the default value. Good luck!

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Should have more up votes in my opinion. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the delegate method from UIScrollViewDelegate [scrollViewShouldScrollToTop](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:)?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work. I initially tried implementing that method along side the UIWebViewDelegate methods, but I didn't think that would work because the web view itself is the scroll view delegate, rather than the web view's delegate. So then I subclassed UIWebView and implemented, but still no luck. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Further investigation: It seems that UIWebView itself doesn't respond to the scroll view delegate methods. Perhaps some other internal object is the scroll view delegate?