# How to trigger scrollsToTop when UITableView is nested inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering if anyone had had any luck triggering scrollsToTop (or by any other means) for a UITableView from the user tapping on the status bar when the UITableView is nested inside a UIScrollView that also observes this function? I know this probably isn't good practice, but in this instance the UX kind of calls for this type of hierarchy.

Either way, I've seen a whole bunch of proposals ranging from private methods (obviously not going to happen) to adding fake windows over the status bar (also not going to happen).

Comment: into which control ur tableview resides ?

Comment: UIScrollView. Sorry. Updated the question.

Comment: have u tried using scrollsToTop for both scroll and table ?

Comment: Yep. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so the answer here is two fold:

1. You cannot have more than one UIScrollView (or classes deriving from or using UIScrollView - i.e. UITableView) on the same UIView with the property scrollsToTop set to YES. Pick the one you want to have the feature and make sure all others are no

   For example, do this:

   ```
   scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
   tableView.scrollsToTop = YES; // or not set
   ```
2. Implement the UIScrollView delegate method `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` and `return YES` if the calling UIScrollView is the UITableView.

Props to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697244/uitableviews-uiwebviews-and-the-scrollstotop-property-trouble) for mentioning the non-multiple `scrollsToTop` option.

Answer (score 12):

Just wanted to share a little function I wrote that helps debug these situations. As others have mentioned, you have to make sure only ONE scroll view has scrollsToTop turned on. If you embed complex view hierarchies it may be difficult to figure out which scroll view is the culprit. Just call this method after your view hierarchy is created, like in viewDidAppear. The level parameter is just to help indentation and you should seed it off with 0.

```
-(void)inspectViewAndSubViews:(UIView*) v level:(int)level {

NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString string];

for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    [str appendString:@"   "];
}

[str appendFormat:@"%@", [v class]];

if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
    [str appendString:@" : UITableView "];
}

if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    [str appendString:@" : UIScrollView "];

    UIScrollView* scrollView = (UIScrollView*)v;
    if (scrollView.scrollsToTop) {
        [str appendString:@" >>>scrollsToTop<<<<"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", str);

for (UIView* sv in [v subviews]) {
    [self inspectViewAndSubViews:sv level:level+1];
}}
```

Call it on your view controller's main view.

In the log, you should see >>>scrollsToTop<<< next to every view that has it turned on, making it easy to find the bug.

Comment: This found my problem! Thanks! I wish I could give you more than an upvote for this little gem.

Comment: Dang! Super helpful method. Typical, "why didn't I think of this" moment.

Comment: You need to look from the view.window down!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that helped me fix this problem is:

- Verify every other `UIScollView` in the view hierarchy is set to `scollsToTop = NO`
- Add sub view controllers as child view controllers using `addChildViewController:` It is not sufficient to only add the view as a subview to the parent's view.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[gridTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Hoping to help you :)