# Stop scrolling to top in UIWebView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, private

I have placed following javascript in my html file.

```
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
    function srk(){
        document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am scrolling my webview by following code with some animation.

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollTo(0,%i);",414*self.initialScrollPosition]];
```

Everything going right, but on problem that I am facing is as follows.

Whenever User/I tap on the status bar of iPhone, WebView Bydefault scrolls to top. 
This should not be done.

Is it possible to prevent inbuilt functionality ?

I know one of the option is as follows.

```
((UIScrollView *)[[myWebView valueForKey:@"_internal"] valueForKey:@"scroller"]).scrollsToTop = NO;
```

But is it valid to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a very tiny UIScrollView in the window. Then tapping the status bar won't scroll the web view to top.

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward way to do this would be to set the `scrollsToTop` property of the `UIScrollView` in the `WebView` to NO.

```
for(UIView *view in [myWebView subviews]) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:([UIScrollView class])]) {
        [(UIScrollView *)view setScrollsToTop:NO];
    }
}
```

I have tested this on iOS 4.0 and 4.3 (iOS 5 seems to not need this).

adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540511/627772).