# scrollsToTop on UIScrollView did not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've set up scrollTopTop property in my `UIScrollView` to YES however, when I tap on my status bar it didn't work. Why is this?

I have a `UIViewController` called A and inside A I have a `UIViewController B`, which has the `UIScrollView`. Is this the reason why it's not working?

Comment: Yes, you can have some instructions from the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361614/iphone-os-tap-status-bar-to-scroll-to-top-doesnt-work-after-remove-add-back)

Comment: The following code can help you do that:

`[[A view] bringToFront:[B view]]`

Comment: @rshahriar just tried that and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of somethings:

- Scrollview is at the front.
- Make sure it's re-enabled after you add/remove your status bar.
- There is only one scrollview because many of them will prevent it from scrolling to top.
- Make sure that B view at front as well of A view.

Sorry but the question has to have more details so that we can help :)

Comment: what other details do you need?

Comment: I never hide/unhode the scroll view and there's only one scroll view

Comment: I've done self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollView on B and did self.view bringSubViewToFront:B.view from A

Comment: hmm..I have an universal app and it works on the iPad but not on the phone

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController B should be added in UIViewController A. 
like this, when you added b.view in a, you should add this code :
 [self addChildViewController:b]

Answer (score 0):

I had an app where scrollsToTop was working. Later on, I added a UICollectionView and scrollsToTop stopped working. After tracking down the offending revision I had to set UICollectionView.scrollsToTop = NO. I overlooked the fact that UICollectionView also inherits from UIScrollView.